# Can't connect to Kafka using CONDUKTOR UI

Tags: apache-kafka, conduktor

I have been connecting to KAFKA using CONDUKTOR Application. But somehow Conduktor connection is disabled (yellow highlighted in the screenshot), and I am unable to connect to kafka, even after rebooting system twice.

Attaching the screenshot. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Not clear where/how/if Kafka is running

Comment: Kafka is running in a docker container. I have verified it through docker ps command.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Docker compose or run command you've used

Answer (score 2):

[To use Conduktor, login is mandatory](https://docs.conduktor.io/misc/data-security#login-licenses)

As mentioned in  Conduktor changelog, from version 1.4.0 onwards it's required to be logged into Conduktor in order to be able to connect to Kafka.

From [Conduktor changelog](https://www.conduktor.io/changelog):

> **Conduktor 1.4.0 (Jan 24, 2020):**
> *We must have to login into Conduktor now. We are integrated with auth0, using a Native app with PKCE oauth flow.*

Answer (score 1):

> Kafka is running in a docker container

Your host cannot resolve docker containers by name. You need to connect to localhost:9092, or whatever the advertised listener you've set up to your host machine

Comment: Just logged in by clicking the login/signup button on the Screenshot I've posted.